# Долгое выполнение кода, запрашивающего данные из удаленной БД

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, sqlite3, pyqt5

Программа на `python 2.7` с `gui` выполненном на `PyQt5`. Есть таблица `QTableWidget`, которая заполняется из лежащей на локальном сервере `SQLite3` базы. Код заполнения таблицы представлен ниже (заранее прошу прощения за вытекшие глаза, я самоучка, впервые увидевший `python` в марте 2017):

```
def mainTableFiller(self):
    # Clear LineEdit. Needed when you return from the deleted files page.
    self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setText('')
    # Check current phase of development.
    if curent_litera == 'rkd':
        # Apply style for 'rkd'
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setToolTip(
            "<html><head/><body><p>Введите децимальный номер.</p><p>Пример: <span style=\" font-weight:600;\">"
            "456321</span></p></body></html>")
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setPlaceholderText("000000")
        # Set INTEGERS ONLY validator for 'rkd' phase
        line_edit_validator_int = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9]+"))
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setValidator(line_edit_validator_int)
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setMaxLength(6)
    elif curent_litera == 'ekd':
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setToolTip(
            "<html><head/><body><p>Введите децимальный номер.</p><p>Пример: <span style=\" font-weight:600;\">"
            "01.05.02.09</span></p></body></html>")
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setPlaceholderText("00.00.00.00")
        line_edit_validator_int = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9\.]+"))
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setValidator(line_edit_validator_int)
        self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setMaxLength(11)

    # Take a list of tuples of existed decimal numbers for current pase and decimal code.
    self.existed_decimals = c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT decimal FROM '%s' WHERE delflag=0 AND litera='%s'"%
                                      (curent_table, curent_litera)).fetchall()
    # Creating empty lists
    files_4_table = []
    self.decimal_numbers_only = []
    # Adding filenames into list
    for tablename in self.existed_decimals:
        if tablename[0][0] == 'f':
            files_4_table.append(tablename)
    files_4_table.sort()
    # Create flag for table filling
    self.show_deleted_flag = 0
    self.ui.table.setRowCount(len(files_4_table))
    self.ui.checkBox.setChecked(False)
    # Fill the table
    for i in range(len(files_4_table)):
        self.ui.table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(curent_rucode + files_4_table[i][0][1:].encode('utf-8')))
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        # Count the number of existing records
        itemscount = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '%s' WHERE decimal LIKE '%s' AND delflag=0 AND "
                                   "recordnumber NOTNULL AND litera='%s'" % (curent_table ,files_4_table[i][0],
                                                                             curent_litera)).fetchall()[0][0]
        if itemscount == 0:
            itemscount = 'Нет Записей'
        #   Set second column text
        item.setData(Qt.EditRole, itemscount)
        self.ui.table.setItem(i, 1, item)
        self.decimal_numbers_only.append(files_4_table[i][0][1:])
    self.decimal_numbers_only.sort()
    # Set compliter for current phase and code
    font14 = QtGui.QFont()
    font14.setPointSize(14)
    completer = QCompleter()
    completer.popup().setFont(font14)
    completer.popup().setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
                                    "alternate-background-color: rgb(85, 87, 83);\n"
                                    "color: rgb(233, 185, 110);\n"
                                    "gridline-color: rgb(233, 185, 110);\n"
                                    "selection-color: rgb(233, 185, 110);\n"
                                    "selection-background-color: rgb(193, 125, 17);")
    self.ui.lineEdit_decimal.setCompleter(completer)
    model = QStringListModel()
    completer.setModel(model)
    self.get_completer(model)
    return self.decimal_numbers_only
```

Проблема в том, что если я обращаюсь к лежащей на локальном диске базе, то код выполняется моментально, задержки не чувствуется. Однако, когда база находится на сетевом диске (сервер предприятия), задержка при заполнении таблицы составляет порядка 1-3 секунд, что очень неприятно. Я сначала списал все на сеть (хотя что, не хватает сотки!?странно). Однако, кинув `exe` одной из сотрудниц, для проверки работоспособности, обнаружил, что на её компьютере все выполняется практически с такой-же скоростью, как если бы база располагалась локально (ну, может соовсем небольшая задержка). Попробовал еще на нескольких компьютерах, у всех лаги ... 
Подскажите, что может быть причиной такого замедленного ответа от БД (как его вообще можно измерить?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что дело в множественных запросах:

```
for i in range(len(files_4_table)):
    # ...
    itemscount = c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '%s' WHERE decimal LIKE '%s' AND delflag=0 AND "
        "recordnumber NOTNULL AND litera='%s'" % (curent_table, files_4_table[i][0], curent_litera)).fetchall()[0][0]
```

Вы делаете запрос к базе `len(files_4_table)` раз, причем последовательно. Если каждый запрос идёт по 50мс и в таблице несколько десятков строк, то как раз получается 1-3 секунды.

А `[0][0]` в конце наводит на подозрения, что вам нужны далеко не все запрашиваемые данные.

Это же SQL, вы наверняка можете объединить все запросы в один, но запрашивать только нужное. (Конкретных улучшений не подскажу, не силен в SQL.)

Comment: вы оказались правы. Решил проблему следующим образом:

`c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*), recordnumber FROM '%s' WHERE delflag=0 AND litera='%s' GROUP BY decimal" % (curent_table, curent_litera)).fetchall()`

А потом пробежался по списку и заполнил таблицу. Если `recordnumber` == `None` прописываем количество вручную. Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0):

**Компиляция python в .exe очень грубое и неправильное дело...** 
Я считаю что вообще есть несколько ключевых факторов, от которых зависит ваша скорость подключения и выполнения.

**1**. Расстояние где находится удаленный сервер

**2**. Ваше интернет подключение, сетевое подключение, у каждого могут возникнуть проблемы с интернет подключением, допустим если вы подключены через кабель, а ваш коллега через `wifi` то скорость подключения через кабель будет соответственно выше.

**3**. Так как `python` **высокоуровневый интерпретируемый язык**, у которого скорость работы намного ниже чем у к**омпилированого**, ваш код будет работать (который приведен выше) гараздо хуже, тем более что данный код не **многопоточный**, и не **многозадачный**.

Если же вы предпочтете сделать его ногопоточным то наверное у вас не будет возникать никаких проблем с скоростью передачи данных. Посоветую статью *https://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/* и *https://vovkd.github.io/gevent-tutorial/*.

Comment: [Да, Python медленный, но меня это не волнует](https://habrahabr.ru/post/329988/)

Comment: По сути: вы предлагаете оптимизировать не там, где находится узкое место. Обычно это не приносит результата и может даже ухудшить производительность. Например, если к перегруженному автомобильному мосту подвести ещё пару магистралей, пробки станут только хуже.